# Failed to Parse While creating Index in elastic search using Python Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, terraform-provider-aws, aws-elasticsearch

Error:

> Failed to parse: http://[https://search-***-kibana-*****************.eu-west-1.**.amazonaws.com/]:9200/example_index: InvalidURL

Details:

***NOTE*** : URL PASSING IS NORMAL LIKE connect_es("https://kibana-endpoint.com"). Also My elastic search connection was successful but while creating Index I was getting this error.

```js
def connect_es(endpoint):
    # Handle aws auth for es
    session = boto3.Session()
    credentials = session.get_credentials()
    awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, session.region_name, 'es',
                       session_token=credentials.token)
    print('Connecting to the ES Endpoint: {endpoint}'.format(endpoint=endpoint))
    #try:
    es_client = Elasticsearch(host=endpoint,
                             port=9200,
                             connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection,
                             timeout=60)
    #print(es_client.hosts)
    print('Connected to elasticsearch')
    request_body = {
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 5,
        "number_of_replicas": 1
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
                "address": {
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "date_of_birth": {
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime",
                    "type": "date"
                },
                "some_PK": {
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "fave_colour": {
                    "index": "analyzed",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "email_domain": {
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }}
    
    print("creating 'example_index' index...")
    
    es_client.indices.create(index = 'example_index', body = request_body)
    mapping = es_client.indices.get_mapping(index="example_index")
```

If there is any mistake please let me know

Comment: Well this doesn't look correct to me: `http://[https:` Are you passing that kind of value there?

Comment: yeah I understood that but I'm using es_client.indicies.create(index)... Not sure what I'm doing wrong ... I'm also passing normal url  I'll edit the question with what I'm passing